# Move the cursor programmatically from one page to other page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, focus, mouse, move

I have 2 pages on the screen (actually more as it is a kind of proprietary web application with a few frames and I cannot figure out actually the whole structure)

I enter the search criteria in a page, I press ‘Enter’ on the keyboard , search is executed and the other view is filled with data. There is a button ‘Confirm’ on this 2nd view and the user has to click on it.

I’d like the user to press ‘Enter’ on the keyboard and ‘Confirm’ to be executed.

If I click on a field on this 2nd view and I press ‘Enter’, ‘Confirm’ is executed so it is a matter of moving the focus of the mouse from the first page to the other one.

How could I achieve this programmatically ?

I have tried the following

```
<SCRIPT FOR=window event=onload language="JScript">
    var focusField = "<%= controller->component_id %>" + '_' + 'NUMBER';
    document.getElementById(focusField).focus();
</SCRIPT>
```

Cursor still in the input field in the first page.

```
<SCRIPT FOR=window event=onload language="JScript">
    var focusField = "<%= controller->component_id %>" + '_' + 'NUMBER';
    alert(document.getElementById(focusField).value);
    document.getElementById(focusField).focus();
</SCRIPT>
```

The value of the field is displayed so the code goes through there

Cursor still in the input field in the first page

```
<SCRIPT FOR=window event=onload language="JScript">
    var focusField = "<%= controller->component_id %>" + '_' + 'NUMBER';
    document.getElementById(focusField).focus();
    alert('1');
    alert('2');
</SCRIPT>
```

Cursor still in the input field in the first page

```
<SCRIPT FOR=window event=onload language="JScript">
    var focusField = "<%= controller->component_id %>" + '_' + 'NUMBER';
    alert('1');
    document.getElementById(focusField).focus();
    alert('2');
</SCRIPT>
```

And the cursor 'moved out' the input field somehow 'miraculously' and 'Enter' works on the 2nd page !!!

Why's that ?

Of course, it is not a solution but I wonder why using alerts (but 2 not 1) achieves my purpose of moving the focus of the mouse.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make it work

```
<SCRIPT FOR=window event=onload language="JScript">

function setFocus()
    {
    var focusField = "<%= controller->component_id %>" + '_' + 'CUSTOMER_STRUCT.BP_NUMBER';
    document.getElementById(focusField).focus();
    }

  window.setTimeout('setFocus()', 40);//1,10,20,30 do not work

</SCRIPT>
```

Any explanation for this ?

It works on my desktop. Could it be that it would not work on other workstations (i.e. the interval would have to be higher) ?